# Get Pie chart to always show total as total number of rows in data

Tags: powerbi

I have data that looks like this:
[image]

Its a row for every user in my clinical trials system, what their contact id is, and what department they're in.

I also have other data that is a row for every protocol we're tracking, one column of which is what department that protocol is in.

I'd like to create a visual like this (pictured, though not working perfectly yet), where I select a study, it shows what department that study is in, and then a pie chart that would show:  "of the 821 total users, 328 of them are in that department"

[image]

It ALMOST works.  All the data is linked to each other, and if I select a different dept the pie chart will change to reflect the users in that department, the problem is it doesn't keep the 'out of 821' as a total.  The entire pie chart just becomes however many rows are in that department.
For instance this pie chart pictured says 328 (100%) because there are 328 people in the Lifespan Cancer Institute department, 328 rows of that.

I want it to be 328 (39%) and show the a slice of the pie about that large.

I COULD just do a pie chart like this that shows every department:
[image]

Which is ALMOST what I want, but the problem is when I select a protocol I dont want the rest of the pie to disappear like this:
[image]

Instead I'd love for all of these slices to turn blue:

[image]

How do I get the pie chart to show percent of total rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pie Chart visual doesn't have an option to show the total. You could get close by building a dynamic title as shown in the next picture. In order to achieve this, I created 3 measures:

```
Selected Users = COUNTROWS('MyTable')
Total Users = COUNTROWS(ALL('MyTable'))
Not Selected Users = [Total Users] - [Selected Users]
Pie Title = FORMAT([Selected Users], "#,##0") & " of " & FORMAT([Total Users],"#,##0") & " users are in the selected study."
```

Add Selected Users and Not Selected Users to the Pie Values.

[image: pie chart]

Another option is to use a Gauge instead of a pie which will show you X out of N.

[image]